# Laravel 5.4 with MongoDB MAC Mojave

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

Hello I having trouble to to install "jenssegers/mongodb": "^3.2" on my local environment.

i have this error: [image]

I have added to my /etc/php.ini full path to extentions="/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/mongodb.so"

restart the php and apache

I have try to find mongodb.ini, fail on that.

I try all the tutorial is google... still no luck

Can any one help me please?

`PHP 7.1.23 (cli) (built: Feb 22 2019 22:08:13) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies`

Comment: Show output of `php -m` command, please

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you forgot to install [MongoDB PHP Driver](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb) itself.

To do that just install it with `pecl`:

```
sudo pecl install mongodb-1.5.3
```

1.5.3 is the last stable version, so I'd recommend to use it rather than the most recent 1.6.0alpha.

Then, don't forget to add it to your `php.ini` (run `php --ini` to see where it's located):

```
extension=mongodb.so
```

To test that it works just run:

```
php -m | grep mongo
```

If you see `mongodb` in output, then it works.